# when generating images on jframe with for loop, why does it stop in the middle of the frame?

Tags: java, frame, imageicon

So I was trying to make a simple PacMan clone, and I've gotten to the stage of adding images, etc. I have two images (so far) which are:
[image: trackball.png] and [image: border.png], trackball.png and border.png.
So I run the code below with `new oicMan();` and this is what I get:
[image: what I get]
And the console output:

```
.
.
.
Placing image border on coordinate (225,250)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,275)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,300)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,325)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,350)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,375)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,400)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,425)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,450)
Placing image border on coordinate (225,475)
```

So it seems to stop at x=225. Can anyone tell me why? Is it a problem with my `for` loops that set the images? Thanks (mainly though, please tell me just why it isn't painting fully.)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class oicMan extends JFrame
{
Container container;
/*
####################
# ##               #
# ## ############# #
# ## ############# #
# ## #             #
# ## # ##### ##### #
# ##   ##### ##### #
# ## # ##### ##### #
#    #             #
####################
 */
    String arena[][] =
    {
    {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    {"#"," ","#","#"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","#"},
    {"#"," ","#","#"," ","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#"},
    {"#"," ","#","#"," ","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#"},
    {"#"," ","#","#"," ","#"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","#"},
    {"#"," ","#","#"," ","#"," ","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#"},
    {"#"," ","#","#"," "," "," ","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#"},
    {"#"," ","#","#"," ","#"," ","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#"},
    {"#"," "," "," "," ","#"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","#"},
    {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    };

    public oicMan()
    {
        super("oicMan");
        setSize(500, 250);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(null);
        container.setBackground(Color.black);

        for(int i = 0; i < arena.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < arena[0].length; j++)
            {
                JLabel label = null;
                if(arena[ i][ j].equals("#"))
                {
                    label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("border.png"));
                    label.setName("border");
                }
                else
                {
                    label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("trackball.png"));
                    label.setName("track");
                }

                container.add(label);
                label.setBounds(i*25,j*25,25,25);
                System.out.println("Placing image "+label.getName()+" on coordinate ("+i*25+","+j*25+")");
            }
        }
        repaint();
        container.validate();
        setContentPane(container);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you may have reversed your rows and your columns when you call label.setBounds(i*25,j*25,25,25); I think changing that line of code to label.setBounds(j*25,i*25,25,25); should fix the problem. The parameters of the JLabel setBounds method are as such: JLabel: setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)

As seen on [this java2s Article](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JLabelsetBoundsintxintyintwidthintheight.htm)

This means that when you think you're setting the y value of the JLabel, you're really setting the x value, and vice-versa.

A good piece of advice is to always read up on the documentation of any libraries you may be using.

I'm always happy to help, though.

Cheers, hope this helps and solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `arena[][]`. It has `10 rows` and `20 columns`, which effectively means your `for` loop will run only for the `200` blocks.

To cover your whole screen, you need to adjust your `arena[][]` accordingly.

**P.S:** `(225,475)` is because of `(i*25+","+j*25)` where `i=9` at max and `j=19` at max.